# Pagination using ul tag does not work in phone

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have created pagination for my page using ul tag, it worked well on computer. But when i access to my page through phone, it is not work. Can anyone tell me what is the problem and solution?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Noone can tell you the problem if you don't post any of your code. It is like calling to doctor and tell him that you are sick without giving any symptom, and expected him to tell you what is wrong with you.

Comment: I see you asked the question again, with more information, so this one can be closed. However, in the future, if you have more information to a question, please edit the original question to add it instead of creating new ones.